# How to change this nested recursion to linear recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion, tail-recursion

I want to change this function of nested recursion to linear recursion or optimally is tail recursion.

```
long long x(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        ret += (n - i) * (n - i) * x(i);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

the origin recursion is

```
X(0)=1; X(n)=n^2*X(0)+(n-1)^2*X1+...+1^2*X(n-1)
```

Comment: Why? What is the problem you have?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i implement a recursion function to solve the X(n)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the origin recursion is

X(0)=1; X(n)=n^2*X(0)+(n-1)^2*X1+...+1^2*X(n-1)

Comment: But apparently the solution you wrote have a problem, that you want to solve. What is the problem with your solution? Why do you want to rewrite it? Please [edit] your question to give us more details.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i want to improve my solution to optimize the time and space. So how does it be implemented which not use loop?

Comment: @HCMUSer I'd prefer to use only loops in combination with `std::stack<long long>` in favor of recursive function calls. That would be much clearer and easier to debug as  a 1st step. Then start to optimize these loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, converted to tail recursion by using an accumulator variable to store the intermediate results of the computation

```
long long x(int n, int i, long long acc) {
    if (i == n) return acc;
    return x(n, i + 1, acc + (n - i) * (n - i) * x(i));
}

long long x(int n) {
    return x(n, 0, 1);
}
```